# How to download normal word export not grid layout export from Jasper soft v6.3.1

Tags: jasper-reports, aspose.words

I am using Jasper soft 6.3.1 and Jasperserver 6.3.0.

I am generating a report book using Jasper.
When I export report book into .docx report, this word file contains grid. Its not like normal document.

How I can download docx like normal ms word document?
Is there any alternative?

Do I need to go for Aspose.com solution, if yes, then how ?

Answer (score 1):

Jasper will always export an docx-output in a table/grid structure. Unfortunately there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirements using [Aspose.Words for JasperReports](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/jasperreports). The output document will be according to the elements of your report. Please read the [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjasperreports/Aspose.Words+for+JasperReports+Documentation) of Aspose.Words for JasperReports. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use a 3rd party library to achieve this. Aspose.Words or any other similar library would do the trick but I strongly suggest that you first take a look at [this library](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/examples) that allows you to create a template in MS Word, with all the necessary formatting and placehoders for the data. At runtime this template is filled with data. You can then choose the output format in .docx, .pdf or .xps format.

```
// Instancing report engine, by assigning the data source 
DocumentGenerator dg = new DocumentGenerator(DataAccess.GetOrderById(7)); 
// Generating report by specifying the report template and the resulting report (as file paths) 
dg.GenerateDocument("example.docx", "example_output.docx");
```